# Splash Screen not working in mobile but working in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, splash-screen

My android app shows 'Unfortunately the app has stopped' error. It contains only the splash screen. It's working perfectly while running in the emulator(Android Nougat). The problem arises only when running in my mobile(API level 22 and Android 5.1). The below is the mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(r,3000);
    }
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

In the splash screen, I'm showing an image only. The below is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_img"
tools:context="com.app.wallpaperandquoteshub.activities.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Kindly help me to solve this:)

Comment: can you send me logs ,see it in the logcat of Android studio, when crash happens,so i can know the reason of crash

Comment: 07-01 00:55:42.255 9235-9235/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.app.wallpaperandquoteshub, PID: 9235
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.wallpaperandquoteshub/com.app.wallpaperandquoteshub.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(

Comment: your code seems fine,error is occuring during infalting your xml file,try using changing  image which you are using to set the background,try using image with less size ,or move the image to drawable-xxhdpi folder.

Comment: I can't find drawable-xxhdpi I moved the image to mipmap-xxhdpi and it works fine